# XSLT - adding tags to a text() node

Tags: xslt

I am trying to implement a text filter that adds a parent node to each text node.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
   <aNewTag><xsl:value-of select="."/></aNewTag>
</xsl:template>
```

This works fine until when I call it indirectly by:

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

But if I call the template directly using

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
```

the new tag disappears.

Can anyone explain me why?

Cheers
Jan

Comment: With the information you gave, this works consistently for me. The <xsl:template match="text()"> is applied no matter what method I used to select text nodes. This means you'll have to post some XML and XSLT code sample that's failing for you.

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit confused by my own code. The complete example looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="a">
        <xsl:with-param name="b">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="a">
    <xsl:param name="b"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$b"/> <!-- here is my error -->
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <aNewTag>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </aNewTag>
</xsl:template>
```

My error was, that I have not seen the `value-of` in the calling template. If I change the `value-of` to a `apply-templates`, everything works fine.

Thanks
Jan

Answer (score 0):

If you use the xal:apply-templates element without a select attribute, the value of select is implicitly set to node() i.e. all the child nodes and hence your text() template is matched.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that in template "a" that the parameter "b" is a node set. To access this, you may have to use an "node-set" extension function in the XSL. It is not part of standard XSLT, so you need to specify an extension.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:call-template name="a">
            <xsl:with-param name="b">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="a">
        <xsl:param name="b"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="ext:node-set($b)">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <aNewTag>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </aNewTag>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This one only works for Microsoft's XML parser (MSXML) only. For other XML processors, such as xsltproc, the namespace "http://exslt.org/common" should be used.

This then allows you to access the node, or nodes, that make up the "b" parameter, although in my example above I have used  to iterate over them.

Here is an article which explains about the node-set

[XML.Com Article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html)